# WebView not used on server PHP redirect

Tags: php, android, redirect, webview

I have a working WebView instance and am able to use loadUrl to display a web page. Everything works correctly and the web page displays in my WebView instance as expected.

However, when I add PHP code to my web page that redirects the displayed web page, it appears that the Android Browser is invoked (i.e., the web-page redirect does not display in my WebView instance, rather it displays in the Android Browser).

The PHP call looks like: header("location: https://myurl.com");

How do I force the PHP redirect to display in my WebView instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix this on the Android side rather than in the PHP.

You need to change the default handling of URLs when they're loaded by overriding [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can do this as follows:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You were spot on and my problem is now solved.